# How to stop url redirection to urls ending with '/' in Django?

Tags: django

On my website, few urls are not crawlable and are returning non 200 response code.

It is happening because those are getting redirected.

```
Example: https://mywebsite.com/fr -> https://mywebsite.com/fr/
```

When I crawl https://mywebsite.com/fr/, it returns me 200 but not for https://mywebsite.com/fr.

Website is built using django.

I am not sure how can I make https://mywebsite.com/fr to return 200 code.

Please advise.

Comment: Have you set the APPEND_SLASH to False in your settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this that redirect you to a URL with a slash at the end by adding this config to your settings.py file

[APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#append-slashd) = False